# How to have Plus sign (+) in <li> list-style?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wonder if we can use the Plus sign in the list style.
Instead of Disc, Circle... in `<li>` List-style, can we have a plus sign?

```
li {list-style: disc...}
```

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style-type for all the standard `list-style-type` settings.

Answer (score 42):

There is no list-style for a plus sign like there is for the disc, circle, etc., but you can achieve similar results using the :before selector together with the content property.

Here is the CSS code to get it to work:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    content: "+";
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Bizarrely, on IE 11, if you then add overriding styles, e.g. to have a `-` when expanded, the browser restores the default item list style and you wind up with a dot under the `-` :(

Comment: The second line of text of the li is not at the same level the first line is.. is there a way to fix this with plain css?

Answer (score 5):

you can use a image instead of it.

```
li{list-style-image:url('...');}
```

Answer (score 3):

With CSS 3 it is better to use the "list-style-type" property.

This CSS code would be the easiest and efficient way:

```
ul {list-style-type: "+";}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above response worked for me, but I got some weird bullet spacing so adding a couple of spaces made it appear the same.

`ul {list-style-type: "+  ";}`